# create a excel-dna function with obligatory arguments

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, excel-dna

> i wanna create a excel-dna function with mandatory arguments! in
>   excel-dna user can enter the null values but in excel UDF user can`t
>   enter the null values and show this message!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The Excel C API (which Excel-DNA uses) does not have a way to define mandatory (or optional) parameters. If your parameter is of type 'object' then you'll get an object of type ExcelMissing if the parameter was not entered in the formula. You can then return an error like 'ExceErrorValue' to get a #VALUE result.